# How to download a file in the New Experience UI

Tags: document-library, library, sharepoint-library, libraries

In the "classic" SharePoint Library UI you could download a file by right clicking on the file and selecting "Download".  I cannot find this option in the new experience UI, is it possible to enable this option or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a document in the new UI, you get all the options at the top:
[image]

Comment: You can also do right click -> Download.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been blind, I looked for both of those options and didn't see them!  :-(

Answer (score 1):

You many not have permission to download but:

[image]

There are two ways to download a document using the new document lib experience

1. Select the document and click on the download
2. Click on the three dots (items menu) and select download